# Python ctypes argument errors

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I wrote a test dll in C++ to make sure things work before I start using a more important dll that I need. Basically it takes two doubles and adds them, then returns the result. I've been playing around and with other test functions I've gotten returns to work, I just can't pass an argument due to errors.
My code is:

```
import ctypes
import string

nDLL = ctypes.WinDLL('test.dll')
func = nDLL['haloshg_add']
func.restype = ctypes.c_double
func.argtypes = (ctypes.c_double,ctypes.c_double)
print(func(5.0,5.0))
```

It returns the error for the line that called "func":

```
ValueError: Procedure probably called with too many arguments (8 bytes in excess)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You probably got the calling conventions mixed up.  I'm guessing you have a C function declared something like this:

```
double haloshg_add(double d1, double s2)
{
    return d1+d2;
}
```

This will use the C calling convention by default.  The simplest approach would be to change the calling convention in your ctypes code:

```
nDLL = ctypes.CDLL('test.dll')
```

If you wanted to change the calling convention in the C code to `stdcall` (to match `ctypes.WinDLL`) then you would do this:

```
double __stdcall haloshg_add(double d1, double s2)
```

Whatever you do, only do one of these changes. If you do both you'll have the reverse failure!

If it were me, I'd just change the Python code to use C calling convention (use `CDLL`). That change has the least impact.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you david for all your help! I'll select your question as the best one as soon as stackoverflow allows me.

Comment: Thanks. I was waiting for this one, after your last question. I expected this would be it, but it's better in separate questions. It's just tidier that way.

Comment: No problem! You're a life-saver, I've never dealt with something like this before and I'm new to python anyway...