# How to correctly create a nim/nimrod windows dll

Tags: windows, dll, nim-lang

I want to create a dll from nim code.
But i failed to register some other exports than "NimMainInner".
Even if i try this simple example its not working:

```
proc Hellow(): cint {.exportc.} =
  echo("hello")
  return 1
```

i've compiled it with `nim c --app:lib libh4x.nim`
and `nim c -d:release --app:lib --no_main libh4x.nim`

i use `Nim Compiler Version 0.11.2 (2015-05-04) [Windows: i386]`

to inspect the dll i use `dllexp.exe`.
I've also tried to load the dll with python ctypes, but none of my exports are shown or are callable. I can see the proc name in the resulting dll with an hexeditor, though.

What have i missed here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [dynlib](http://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#foreign-function-interface-dynlib-pragma-for-export) pragma was missing. So i changed the definition to:

```
proc Hellow(): cint {.exportc,dynlib.} =
  echo("hello")
  result = 1
```

now it works.

Note: If you use this with pythons ctypes and with function parameters make sure to use `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary` instead of `ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary`:
[Python ctypes argument errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267434/python-ctypes-argument-errors)

and to declare the function like this:

```
proc myinit(procid : int) {.cdecl,exportc,dynlib.} =
  discard
```